# Cartthrob: Shopping cart with over 100 products in cart

Tags: add-on, ecommerce, cartthrob

Has anyone used Cartthrob with a super stuffed cart of 100 to 200 items in cart?

I'm attempting to create a system in the style of an online supermarket shopping cart where you can see all your products in a single cart.

Adding products works ok (could be quicker, 5s load time), but when using the update cart form takes minutes to load.

Comment: Could Brilliant Retail or Expresso Store do this job better?

Comment: I'm not sure that the specific module used for this would matter much. I haven't looked, but I'd imagine all three ecommerce modules use a similar method of storing the cart.

Comment: I think you might be best asking this on the CT forums if you haven't already. The BNI guys are the ones best placed to give a definitive answer, but I don't think any of them are currently members here.

Comment: I have already http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/7470/

Comment: Have you looked at your debugging output yet? That should tell you where the issue is occurring on the save.

Comment: Debugging shows long list of add_to_cart_form
each taking about half a second to return data.

Comment: Speaking generally, there's probably not much *you* could do to improve this situation. How many SQL queries are your pages generating? I expect the code would need to be improved to handle this situation. I know we haven't tested Store with those sorts of numbers.

Comment: Problem seems to be when calling classes: (0.099640 / 16.65MB) -> Method Called: cart_items_info
(2.355200 / 21.43MB) -> Data Returned 
.....
(47.597643 / 24.17MB) Calling Class/Method: Cartthrob/add_to_cart_form
(47.597729 / 24.17MB) -> Class Called: Cartthrob
(47.598249 / 24.17MB) -> Method Called: add_to_cart_form
(48.008619 / 24.22MB) -> Data Returned

Answer (score 1):

As MediaGirl mentioned in the comments, you should look at your debugging output. There is nothing about CartThrob itself (or loading 100 products) that should cause the slowness that you describe. The debugging output will give you more info though. It's possible that it's not even CartThrob which is the core cause of your problems.

You might also want to try using your Chrome / Firefox developer tools to see if there is anything funky going on with loading resources.

Otherwise, you need to post more information. For example, does everything load fine when you only have a handful of products that you are working with?

Comment: I just did a comparison with an older build. Added over 30 products and less than a sec to load, on my new site it takes over 20 secs. Time to strip down the engine! I'll post back if I find the problem.

Comment: Not solved just yet! I'm now having the same issue with the add_to_cart_form tag pair. It's used inside the exp:channel:entries tag pair to list out the products. When the add_to_cart_form tags are outside the exp:channel:entries tags it renders fast, the problem is I need to grab the entry_id so it can't go outside.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap the {exp:cartthrob:update_cart_form} tag round the {exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info} and not the other way round :)

Comment: That's it! this stops the update_cart_form from being called over and over again.